# Replacing Comma character with Serial No

Tags: vba, ms-word, str-replace

In place of
*Comma space Anil, Comma space Sunil etc*
as illustrated below:

> *, Anil, Sunil etc*

.
I want to Give Serial No in Same Line like:

> *(1) Anil (2) Sunil etc*

**'The Procedure has to do a lot of unnecessary work. Is there a better way.**

'Put Curser anywhere befor first Comma

```
Sub GiveSerialToLinerPoints()
   

x = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Paragraphs(1). _
Range.End).Paragraphs.Count
i = 0
For Each char In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(x).Range.Characters
    
        If char = "," Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
Next char

TotalCommas = i

For i = 1 To TotalCommas
    With Selection
            .StartIsActive = False
            .Extend Character:=","
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            .MoveLeft
            .Expand Unit:=wdCharacter

                    If .Text = "," Then
                            .Text = " (" & i & ")"
                    End If
        End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ","
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    i = i + 1
    .Text = "(" & i & ")"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " commas replaced."
End Sub
```

To limit the F/R to just the paragraph the insertion point is in, you could use:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
With Selection.Paragraphs.First
  Set Rng = .Range
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ","
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .InRange(Rng) Then
        i = i + 1
        .Text = "(" & i & ")"
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to tell that I want this to be done only in the paragraph in which the insertion point is. This changes all the commas in the document. I tried giving paragraph number variable but it did nothing. Like: "With Active document.paragraphs(x).range" Thanks.

Comment: You really should include such essential details in your question. See updated answer.

Comment: I also got to know How to Limit F/R to a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

For the output, once the string is captured from your document, you could use `Split()` to split the string with the comma as delimiter, then via the loop build the new result string.

Something like:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim StartString As String
    Dim ResultString As String
    Dim TempSplit As Variant
    Dim LoopCounter As Long
    
    StartString = "Anil, Sunil"
    TempSplit = Split(MyString, ",")
    
    For LoopCounter = 1 To UBound(TempSplit) + 1
        ResultString = ResultString & TempSplit(LoopCounter - 1) & "(" & LoopCounter & ")"
    Next LoopCounter
    
    Debug.Print ResultString
End Sub
```

This starts with the string:

> "Anil, Sunil"

And prints to the *immidiate* window:

> (1)Anil (2)Sunil

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to count backwards over the `Characters` :

```vb
Sub GiveSerialToLinerPoints()
   
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, n As Long
    
    Set rng = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
    n = 1 + Len(rng.Text) - Len(Replace(rng.Text, ",", "")) '# of commas plus one
    
    For i = rng.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rng.Characters(i).Text = "," Then
            rng.Characters(i).Text = " (" & n & ")"
            n = n - 1
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Characters(1) = "(1) " & rng.Characters(1).Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, This Also worked. In addition I learnt how to read every character in a paragraph or any range object.

Answer (score 0):

'Site:my account in StackOverflow
'By Samual Everson

' in place of  Comma space Anil Sharaf Comma space Sunil Sharaf *Like*
'**, Anil Sharaf, Sunil Sharaf, etc.** How to Give Serial No in Same Line Like:
'**(1) Anil Sharaf (2) Sunil Sharaf etc**

**'Select the  Comma delemited Words.**
'then Run this macro by F5

```
  Sub GiveSerialToCommaDelimitedWordsSelectMethod_Quick()
Dim StartString As String
Dim ResultString As String
Dim TempSplit As Variant
Dim LoopCounter As Long


If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
MsgBox "You need to select the Comma Delimited Words."
  Exit Sub
    End If
    StartString = Selection.Text
  TempSplit = Split(StartString, ",")

For LoopCounter = 1 To UBound(TempSplit)
    ResultString = ResultString & "(" & LoopCounter & ")" & TempSplit(LoopCounter) & " "
Next LoopCounter

Selection.Text = ResultString
End Sub
```